# Some keys are not used by the HfArgumentParser

Tags: deep-learning, huggingface-transformers, nlp-question-answering

`raise ValueError(f"Some keys are not used by the HfArgumentParser: {sorted(unused_keys)}") ValueError: Some keys are not used by the HfArgumentParser: ['max_len', 'model_name_or_path', 'use_cache']`

The same code runs successfully in local machine.
It throws the above error when ran in a server.

Is something has to be done with transformers package ? If so how to resolve this ?

Tried reinstalling the latest transformers version in local machine. it ran successfully.
Installed latest version in server. It still throwed the error.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove these unused keys. For example, remove `use_cache`, `model_name_or_path`, and `max_len` from the dict that contains these strings and be passed to `HfArgumentParser`.

Hope it is helpful.